# .NET equivalent of Java's BufferedReader

Tags: c#, java, bufferedreader

I have that code in Java

```
public void read() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
    String requestURL = null;
    Vector property = new Vector();
    String line;
       //MORE OF CODE
}
```

If You need full code [here](http://pastebin.com/aFrRX4im) is paste.

I want rewrite that to C#

But i don't know which is equivalent to BufferReader.
I have socket, and i want read from socket InputStream (with UTF8)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for `StreamReader` in C#.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this ought to do you, though I'm sure I'm missing a ton of exceptional condition handling and minor things like, oh, graceful server shutdown.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  string      localMachineName    = Dns.GetHostName() ;
  IPHostEntry localMachineInfo    = Dns.GetHostEntry( localMachineName ) ;
  IPAddress   localMachineAddress = localMachineInfo.AddressList[0] ;
  IPEndPoint  localEndPoint       = new IPEndPoint( localMachineAddress , PORT_NUMBER ) ;

  using ( Socket server = new Socket( localEndPoint.AddressFamily , SocketType.Stream , ProtocolType.Tcp ) )
  {
    server.Bind(   localEndPoint                    ) ;
    server.Listen( PENDING_CONNECTIONS_QUEUE_LENGTH ) ;

    while ( true )
    {
      using ( Socket        connection       = server.Accept()                                         )
      using ( NetworkStream connectionStream = new NetworkStream( connection       , FileAccess.Read , false ) )
      using ( TextReader    connectionReader = new StreamReader(  connectionStream , Encoding.UTF8  ) )
      {
        IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint = (IPEndPoint) connection.RemoteEndPoint ;

        string line ;
        while ( null != (line=connectionReader.ReadLine()) )
        {
          line = line.Trim() ;
          Console.WriteLine( "Client says: {0}" , line ) ;
          if ( string.Equals( "exit"     , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
          if ( string.Equals( "quit"     , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
          if ( string.Equals( "goodbye"  , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
          if ( string.Equals( "good-bye" , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
        }

        connection.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both ) ;
        connection.Close() ;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

If you want to buffer the stream, just decorate the `NetworkStream` instance with a `BufferedStream`:

```
using ( Socket     connection       = server.Accept()                                                            )
using ( Stream     connectionStream = new NetworkStream( connection       , FileAccess.Read , false            ) )
using ( TextReader connectionReader = new StreamReader( new BufferedStream( connectionStream ) , Encoding.UTF8 ) )
{
  IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint = (IPEndPoint) connection.RemoteEndPoint ;

  string line ;
  while ( null != (line=connectionReader.ReadLine()) )
  {
    line = line.Trim() ;
    Console.WriteLine( "Client says: {0}" , line ) ;
    if ( string.Equals( "exit"     , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
    if ( string.Equals( "quit"     , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
    if ( string.Equals( "goodbye"  , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
    if ( string.Equals( "good-bye" , line , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ) break ;
  }

  connection.Shutdown( SocketShutdown.Both ) ;
  connection.Close() ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following would be comparable.

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Socket.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
    while(reader.Peek() >= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine()); // or something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but from socket i don't have GetStream. (start with "G" - GetHashCode, GetSocketOption, GetType).

Comment: @WiktorTkaczyński, please take a look at `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` classes: they have the `GetStream()` method.

Comment: @WiktorTkaczyński But from that socket you could create a NetworkStream as such : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-5.0#examples

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want.  BufferedReader buffers the data from *another* reader.  If you just want buffered reads, you can use something like StreamReader depending how you want to read data.